# how to make radio button using powershell and function depending upon user inputs?

Tags: vb.net, powershell, batch-file, vbscript, powershell-2.0

i was looking to set time to my computer for that i m scripting  3 radio buttons of three different countries so that user can set the time zone by selecting one of the radio button.

Please help.

Comment: You can do it with HTA and vbscript !

Comment: check [**this**](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/mshta/ui.extensions/radioButtons.bat) and call it like `call radioButtons.bat opt1 opt2 opt3`

Comment: @Hackoo can you please help with vbscript

Answer (score 2):

check the [radioButtons.bat](https://github.com/npocmaka/batch.scripts/blob/master/hybrids/mshta/ui.extensions/radioButtons.bat) . Having it in the same directory as your script you can try something like:

```
@echo off

for /f %%# in ('radioButtons.bat bulgaria cambodia zimbabwe') do set country=%%#

if %country% equ 1 (
    set "timezone=+1"
)

if %country% equ 2 (
    set "timezone=+2"
)

if %country% equ 3 (
    set "timezone=+3"
)

echo %timezone%
```

it will create an window like this

[image]
and will print the result to the console where it can be processed by `for /f`

Comment: @FoxZ  to change the time zone settings you'll have to call [tzutil](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh875624(v=ws.11).aspx). I think it requires admin privileges. To simply change the date and time you can use TIME command (which also requires admin permissions for changing the settings. )